# Testing statistics behind decision tree

Tags: statistics, decision-tree

I found myself a problem about statistics. I am looking for solution...

Like if you have two decision trees, and one tree has dropped 970 leaves and the other has dropped 1027, you assume they should drop the same number of leaves.

How do you test if this number of counts is significantly different?

Answer (score 0):

We use Poisson distribution for trees. And for over 1000 leaves in tree it's almost normal distribution plot. From this point it's easy to use statistics for it.